# R Sweave user defined function

Tags: r, sweave

I´m writing up a small function giving a combined conditional density and empirical cumulative distribution plot.

```
cdpl<-function(df,dep,indep){
    attach(df)

    cdplot(dep~indep,xlab=deparse(substitute(indep)),ylab=deparse(substitute(dep)))
    g<-indep
    ec<-ecdf(indep)
    lines(knots(ec),as.numeric(names(table(ec(g)))),col="red",lw=3)
    detach(df)
    }
```

This works fine, however when  I try to sweave it my luck is all out...

```
<<fig1,fig=T>>=
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
print(cdpl(tre,A,B))
print(cdpl(tre,A,C))
@
```

> Sweave("re.rnw")
>   Writing to file re.tex
>   Processing code chunks ...

1 : echo term verbatim eps pdf (label=fig1)

Error:  chunk 1 (label=fig1) 
Error in model.frame.default(formula = dep ~ indep) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'dep'

How can this be when it works allright outside sweave?

//M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of attaching (causes all types of problems) pass the data frame as the data argument in cdplot and see if that works.